# Using SAS to select multiples of 5

Tags: sas

Assuming a dataset that have a variable with various numbers. I want to select all numbers if they are multiples of 5. The following codes are what I have tried.

```
data have;
input number 25.0;
cards;
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
;
run;


data want;
set have;
do  i=1 to 999;
if number=5*i then select=1;
end;
run;
```

Are there any better way to select multiple of 5 or other number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SAS provides the [`MOD()` function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/64248/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_langref_sect193.htm), which takes the remainder after division by a number. This is similar to the `%` (modulo) operator in many other programming languages, which does the same thing.

By definition, a number `n` is a multiple of 5 if `n mod 5` is equal to `0`. We can use this check to filter our data.

The following DATA step will output to `want` only the rows in `have` where `number` is divisible by 5:

```
data want;
    set have;
    if mod(number, 5)=0;
run;
```